# ProLog Lists Show Result

Tags: prolog

Hi guys I am new to prolog and I am trying to complete my first project.I have a family tree(family/3) with the 3 arguments(person(dad),person(mom),. list with all of the children).Currently I have 3 families on my knowledge base.What I am trying to accomplish is show the names of the mothers that have more than 3 children.Any help would be great.
This is the code so far.

```
family(person(tom,right,date(17,May,1950),works(mathematician)),person(ann,right,date(29,May,1951),unemployed),
[person(pat,right,date(5,May,1983),unemployed),person(max,right,date(15,May,1973),unemployed),[]]).

family(person(nick,wellbard,date(15,September,1954),works(electrician)),person(cathrine,wellbard,date(11,March,1957),unemployed),
[person(john,wellbard,date(15,May,1985),works(musician)),person(mike,wellbard,date(25,May,1989),unemployed),
person(chloe,wellbard,date(13,October,1991),unemployed),[]]).

family(person(john,brock,date(17,January,1951),works(programmer)),person(mary,brock,date(19,March,1952),works(teacher)),
[person(tony,brock,date(20,May,1975),unemployed),person(sasha,brock,date(1,April,1979),unemployed),
person(josh,brock,date(29,April,1982),unemployed),[]]).
```

I'm thinking something like `family(_,X,_):-[X,Y,Z|]` so I can show the names of the mothers that have at least 3 children.
Excuse me for any mistakes I am novice at ProLog,any help or guidance would be great,thanks :)

Comment: Why all your children lists end with [] ?

Answer (score 0):

you're on track, more or less...
try

```
mother_with_at_least_3_sons(M) :-
   family(_,M,[_,_,_|_]).
```

**edit** if you can't change the children list, removing the useless [] at end, the rule should actually read

```
mother_with_at_least_3_sons(M) :-
   family(_,M,[_,_,_,_|_]).
```

Comment: this matches families with only 2 sons too (there's an empty list at the end of the sons list).

Answer (score 0):

here is my answer to your question.

**% we "say" to prolog if you find a family that has Dad,Mom,Kids**

**% where Kids is a list that has more than 3 elements ( obtained with length )**

**% then give me the name and surname of Mom**

```
more_than_three_children(MotherName,MotherSurname) :- family(Dad,Mom,Kids),
                                                      length(Kids,NumberOfKids),
                                                      NumberOfKids > 3,
                                                      Mom=person(MotherName,MotherSurname,_,_).
```

**% in order to find all mothers we can use the findall predicate**

**% the first argument is OBJECT , we create an instance of the object using the GOAL**

**% the second argument is the GOAL. if prolog "finds" some structure that satisfies that GOAL**

**% it will place it in the List ( which is the third argument )**

```
mother_list(List) :- findall((MotherName,MotherSurname),more_than_three_children(MotherName,MotherSurname),List).
```